# How to convert datetime format 2021-08-17T22:42:00.000Z to Date Format YYYY-MM-DD in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, time

I have a script inputting dates in Date/Time format in my Google Sheet as a string as follows:

2021-08-17T22:42:00.000Z

I need to do some date calculations on this column and need the date in format YYYY-MM-DD without the Time information. Is there a way to convert the above string to date?

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=left(A1,10)*1
```

and then apply the format you wish.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A, "T")*1,,1)
```